# Render multiple simultaneous AR targets with Scenekit and Vuforia

Tags: swift, scenekit, vuforia

I'm following the example project from here: https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift

I was able to increase the number of simultaneous image targets it tracks by adding the following line in the initTracker() method in VuforiaManager.mm:

```
Vuforia::setHint(Vuforia::HINT_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGE_TARGETS, 4);
```

The example project draws a 3d cube on top of the targets, but I need to be able to have it do this for multiple targets detected at the same time, not just one at a time. How can I modify the code from this project in order to accomplish this?